# Why does my retrained model have poor accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to retrain the final layer of a pretrained model using the same dataset (MNIST handrwitten digit dataset) but the accuracy of the retrained model is much worse than the initial model. My initial model gets an accuracy of ~98% while the retrained model accuracy varies between 40-80% depending on the run. I get similar results when I don't bother to train the first 2 layers at all.

Here's a visualization of what I'm trying to do.[image]

And the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

epochs1 = 150
epochs2 = 300
batch_size = 11000
learning_rate1 = 1e-3
learning_rate2 = 1e-4

# Base model
def base_model(input, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('base_model', reuse=reuse):
        layer1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(input, 300)
        features = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(layer1, 300)
        return features


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('./mnist/', one_hot=True)

image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

features1 = base_model(image, reuse=False)
features2 = base_model(image, reuse=True)

# Logits1 trained with the base model
with tf.variable_scope('logits1', reuse=False):
    logits1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(features1, 10, tf.nn.relu)

# Logits2 trained while the base model is frozen
with tf.variable_scope('logits2', reuse=False):
    logits2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(features2, 10, tf.nn.relu)

# Var Lists
var_list_partial1 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='logits1')
var_list_partial2 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='base_model')
var_list1 = var_list_partial1 + var_list_partial2
var_list2 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='logits2')

# Sanity check
print("var_list1:", var_list1)
print("var_list2:", var_list2)

# Cross Entropy Losses
loss1 = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits1, labels=label)
loss2 = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits2, labels=label)

# Train the final logits layer
train1 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate1).minimize(loss1, var_list=var_list1)
train2 = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate2).minimize(loss2, var_list=var_list2)

# Accuracy operations
correct_prediction1 = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits1, 1), tf.argmax(label, 1))
correct_prediction2 = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits2, 1), tf.argmax(label, 1))
accuracy1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction1, "float"))
accuracy2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction2, "float"))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    batches = int(len(mnist.train.images) / batch_size)

    # Train base model and logits1
    for epoch in range(epochs1):
        for batch in range(batches):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            sess.run(train1, feed_dict={image: batch_xs, label: batch_ys})

    # Train logits2 keeping the base model frozen
    for epoch in range(epochs2):
        for batch in range(batches):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            sess.run(train2, feed_dict={image: batch_xs, label: batch_ys})

    # Print the both models after training
    accuracy = sess.run(accuracy1, feed_dict={image: mnist.test.images, label: mnist.test.labels})
    print("Initial Model Accuracy After training final model:", accuracy)
    accuracy = sess.run(accuracy2, feed_dict={image: mnist.test.images, label: mnist.test.labels})
    print("Final Model Accuracy After Training:", accuracy)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove non-linearity from the "logits1" and "logits2".

I changed your code to:

```
# Logits1 trained with the base model
with tf.variable_scope('logits1', reuse=False):
    #logits1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(features1, 10, tf.nn.relu)
    logits1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(features1, 10, None)

# Logits2 trained while the base model is frozen
with tf.variable_scope('logits2', reuse=False):
     #logits2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(features2, 10, tf.nn.relu)
     logits2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(features2, 10, None)
```

and result changed to:

```
Initial Model Accuracy After training final model: 0.9805
Final Model Accuracy After Training: 0.9658
```

P.S. And 300 + 300 neurons is too much for MNIST classifier, but i think your point is not to classify MNIST :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by non-linearity can you give an example or elaborate?  I've edited my post to show how attempted to remove it but I'm not sure if it's what you meant.

Also you're right, this is just a toy example I'm testing with before I step things up.

Comment: It worked but how did you know to do that?  What's the theory behind this solution?

Comment: The theory is simple: you should not use ReLU right before softmax, :)
i launched your code several times, and first model trained to 0.7 - 0.98 accuracy from launch to launch. This is very big range, then first model was not robust. I looked at model, and found non-linearity before softmax.